Manifolds double covered by $RP^3 \# RP^3$
I am trying to find all orientable  3-manifolds that are double covered by $RP^3 \# RP^3$. Of course it double covers itself but are there even any other manifolds? The fundamental group of $RP^3 \# RP^3$ I think has more than one subgroup of Index 2 so I guess there might exist another manifold.
Also in general is the number of manifolds that are double covered by the same manifold equal to the number of subgroups of index 2 of the fundamental group of the double cover?

which is the fundamental group presentation?

$Z_2 * Z_2$. How do I find from this all $Z_2$ actions?

You have it backwards. If $M$ is double covered, then $\pi_1(M)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/2\ast \mathbb{Z}/2$ as an index $2$ subgroup. Since abelianization preserves colimits, this means that $H_1(M)$ contains $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2$ as an index $2$ subgroup, so it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/4$ or to $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$. I don't know how far you get with this though.

Even more, by UCT $H^1(M)=0$, so by Poincare duality $H_2(M)=0$. Since the Euler characteristic is $0$, we must have $H_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ (use $\mathbb{F}_2$-coefficients).
